# How to create Avro with union types in Python

Tags: python, avro, union-types

I try to convert a JSON file to Avro in Python, the caveat is that the schema has a union type. More specifically, in the minimal non-working example the JSON file is just `{"field1": {"int": 17} }` while the schema is `{"type": "record", "name": "ROOT", "fields": [{"name": "field1", "type": ["null","int"] }] }`.

My example is correctly recognized by avro-tools (the command `java -jar avro-tools.jar fromjson --schema-file schema.avsc sample1.json > sample1.avro` generates a valid Avro file). However, the Python libraries have a problem and do not recognise my JSON as valid for my schema. Below you may find a sample code

```
import json
import avro
from avro.datafile import DataFileWriter, DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumWriter, DatumReader

schema = """{"type": "record", "name": "ROOT", "fields": 
 [{"name": "field1", "type": ["null","int"] }] }"""

example1="""{"field1": {"int": 17} }"""

schema_parsed = avro.schema.Parse(schema)

with open('TEST.avro', 'wb') as f:
    writer = DataFileWriter(f, DatumWriter(), schema_parsed)
    writer.append(json.loads(example1))
    writer.close()
```

which is based on [this blog post](https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2019/11/29/handling-avro-files-in-python/); it generates an error message `AvroTypeException: The datum {'field1': {'int': 17}} is not an example of the schema...`

What is the right way to handle such examples in Python?

I use Python 3.10.10, the outcome of `pip list | grep avro` is: avro-python3 version 1.10.2, fastavro version 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

The standard python avro library does not currently support reading avro encoded JSON. However, `fastavro` does and it would look something like this:

```py
from fastavro import json_reader

schema = {
    'name': 'ROOT',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'field1', 'type': ['null', 'int']},
    ]
}

records = []

# If you have the JSON in a file already, do this
with open('file_with_avro_json.json', 'r') as fo:
    avro_reader = json_reader(fo, schema)
    for record in avro_reader:
        records.append(record)

# If it's not in a file, you can do this:
from io import StringIO
sio = StringIO("""{"field1": {"int": 17} }""")
avro_reader = json_reader(sio, schema)
for record in avro_reader:
    records.append(record)
```

In your example code it looks like you are trying to write it back out as an avro binary object, so you could add this block to write it out:

```py
from fastavro import writer

with open('output.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, schema, records)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are **two** incompatible specifications for the JSON file: the one used by avro-tools (which is based on Java) and the one used by the native Python library, which is quite confusing.

The Python library requires a simpler syntax for the JSON file in the fields with union types and changing one line of code to `example1="""{"field1": 17 }"""` removes the error.

Comment: You are confusing the avro json specification (which requires the type hint like `{'field1': {'int': 17}}`) and the in-memory version of an avro data (which for the python libraries is a dictionary object that looks extremely similar to the avro json spec except it doesn't use those type hints).

The standard python avro library does not support avro json, but if you use `fastavro` there is a `json_read` that can read your avro json (https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_reader.html)